# running nested jobs in spark

Tags: json, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark. I have a list of gziped json files on s3 which I have to access, transform and then export in parquet to s3. Each json file contains around 100k lines so parallelizing it wont make much sense(but i am open to parallelizing it), but there are around 5k files which I have parallelize. My approach is pass the json file list to script -> run parallelize on the list -> run map(? this is where I am getting blocked). how do I access and transform the json create a DF out of the transformed json and dump it as parquet into s3.

Comment: You can pass a coma concatenated list of paths to a reader.

Comment: Depending on your spark installation, you may be able to read s3 directly from spark like this:  `rawtext  = sc.textFile('s3://bucket/file')`

Comment: When i am dumping parquet it should be against each json meaning 1.json => 1.parquet, this consistence will be lost if i comma seprate file names.

Answer (score 0):

To read json in a distributed fashion, you will need to parallelize your keys as you mention. To do this while reading from s3, you'll need to use boto3. Below is a skeleton sketch of how to do so. You'll likely need to modify distributedJsonRead to fit your use case.

```
import boto3
import json
from pyspark.sql import Row

def distributedJsonRead(s3Key):
    s3obj = boto3.resource('s3').Object(bucket_name='bucketName', key=key)
    contents = json.loads(s3obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
    return Row(**contents)

pkeys = sc.parallelize(keyList) #keyList is a list of s3 keys
dataRdd = pkeys.map(distributedJsonRead)
```

Boto3 Reference: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html

Edit: to address the 1:1 mapping of input files to output files

Later on, it's likely that having a merged parquet data set would be easier to work with. But if this is the way you need to do it, you could try something like this

```
for k in keyList:
     rawtext = sc.read.json(k) # or whichever method you need to use to read in the data
     outpath = k[:-4]+'parquet'
     rawtext.write.parquet(outpath)
```

I don't think you will not be able to parallelize these operations if you want a 1:1 mapping of json to parquet files. Spark's read/write functionality is designed to be called by the driver, and needs access to sc and sqlContext. This is another reason why having 1 parquet directory is likely the way to go.

Comment: but i also want to know from which file the parquet was generated i.e. if suppose json is in `s3://bucket/json/12/3/abc.json` its result goes to `s3://bucket/json/12/3/abc.parquet`

Comment: around 20GB of data is generated per day. And generally around i have to analyze a day or two data in such case merging wont help. So basically you are saying I cant parallelize file read.